# What is the procedure in the temple if the menorah lights burned for more than 24 hours?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, temple-service-avoda, menorah--in-temple

One of the forms of service in the temple was preparing and lighting the candles each new day. I would like to know what a kohen was supposed to do if he found that the flame in the menorah was continuing to burn from the previous day and thus did not require any new action. Was he supposed to extinguish the flame and relight it or leave it alone and skip that portion of the service?

Comment: See Mishnah Tamid 3:9 and 6:1